# Which of these?

Tags: grammar, construction

> 1. I am going to share three responsibilities of our class monitor.
> 2. I am going to share the three responsibilities of our class monitor.

Which of the two above conveys a message that "there are only three responsibilities of our class monitor and I am going to share these" and "there are many responsibilities of our class monitor but I am only going to share three"

And what about the this:

> 3. I am going to share our class monitor's three responsibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am going to share three responsibilities of our class monitor. ***(only three responsibilities of the many he has)***

> I am going to share the three responsibilities of our class monitor. ***(he only has three)***

> I am going to share our class monitor's three responsibilities.

is correct and has the meaning ***he only has three responsibilities***. However, it sounds less common, in spoken language at least.

Comment: Thank you very much, it was really helpful :)

Comment: Does "Its three features are...." mean only three of the many it has? How to write a sentence in structure like this to mean the only three features?

Comment: Your first example means: "The (only) three features of something". If it has more than three you say "Three of the features of something" or simply "Three features of something"

Comment: What about "Its three features are...." I am sorry to ask it again and again. I got the above structures and what they mean but I wonder what this one conveys. Say "it" here means an electronic device.

Comment: I have already explained that: Your first example ("Its three features are...") means : "The (only) three features of something (of it)".

Comment: Ohh I am sorry, Thank you so much.

Comment: The version "I am going to share our class monitor's three responsibilities" means to me that the monitor has only those three responsibilities.

Comment: @AnsreasB: Well spotted, It is clear in my mind, it beats me why I wrote differently. I have edited my answer.